# line integral using greens formula

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I want to solve this line integral [integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ojUT.png), where D is defined by [inequality 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNtvd.png) and [inequality 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1s2y.png). I am aware that I have to parameterize using elliptical coordinates but my problem is how am i supposed to determine the range of the angle?

x=2*r*cos(Θ) 
y=r*sin(Θ)

I know that 0 ≤r≤ 1 and I know that the upper limit for the angle is  π/2 but cant figure out how to determine the lower limit.

My thought is since the line intersects with the ellipse at x=√2 and y=1/√2, we can just use tan(Θ)=(1/√2)/√2.

 But this gives me the wrong limit but i dont understand why